# In the Eclipse, how to set environment variables for the whole project (Ubuntu)

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, ubuntu-14.04, aws-sdk

Thanks for viewing my question first! I am developing a PHP project with AWS in the Eclipse.

As the AWS SDK needs the environment variables of AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, I am struggling with how to set them in Eclipse. Currently, it works perfectly in Terminal and single file in Eclipse. As I can set the two environment variables for single file:[image]

I aslo tried to set them in etc/environment, but I do not know it does not work.

Could you tell me how to set the environment for the whole PHP project?

System: Ubuntu 14.04
Eclipse version: 
"Eclipse for PHP Developers
Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160218-0600"

Looking forward to your reply and thank you so much!
Sincerely

Answer (score 0):

under the run configuration, you can set the environment variables for whole project. Select the second radio button "Replace native environment with specified ..."Please take a look at attached screen shot.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But how should I set the variables for the whole project? I don't think replace native environment with specified will work and I tried.  Besides, I think our interface is quite different.

Comment: I tried and it worked. Do you still see issues? I can even print the values anywhere im the project just to cross verify.

Comment: It still does not work for me.  I still cannot see how did you set the environment variables for the whole project. In your screen capture, the Name is "test", I think it can only be used for your file of test.php (test.java). Could you explain more detailed? By the way, how to print the environment variables in the eclipse in PHP? Looking forward to your reply and thank you so much!

Comment: Hi Spider, Launch configurations are specific to a project instead of a file. I am not sure why it does not work for you.
To print env variables, I have a java code:
        System.out.println(System.getenv("JAVA_HOME"));

I am not sure in php how do we do that. Probably below code works for this purpose which I got from internet:
string getenv ( string $varname );

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! But I think the reason is we have different version of Eclipse. My run configurations is only for single file.